# What's the difference between NPN and PNP transistors?

Tags: pnp, npn

This is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12480/whats-the-difference-between-npn-and-pnp-transistors).

I would like to know what the **differences in their characteristics** are. I'm thinking for example about their majority carriers (electrons for NPN, holes for PNP). Does that mean that NPNs are faster?

Answer (score 2):

This question is far far far too well answered on the web to be sensibly answered here. This really is a "Google can tell you better than we can" type question.

Excellent examples include.

[Wikipedia - very good discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor)

---

Electronics tutorials- transistors.

- [PNP](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_3.html)-
- [NPN](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html)

and 6 other transistor related pages.

---

**Much more ...**

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws is an excellent site, but doesn't seem to answer Federico's question, other than how it's used in a circuit, which was already answered in [the question Federico referred to](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12480/whats-the-difference-between-npn-and-pnp-transistors) .