# Why do electrons move faster than holes in a semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductors

When an electron leaves, then only a hole is created, and when another electron fills it, then only the hole moves, so in that way, both should conduct current at the same speed.  Yet I've been told that holes have higher mobility than electrons.
Please explain how that can be, I'm confused.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_mobility (also covers holes)

Comment: a simplified TLDR: there are two "types" of electrons at any given time: free electrons and "bound" electrons. Free electrons move freely in space, bound electrons can only jump from one covalent bond to another. Naturally, bound electrons move slower than free electrons. This is the answer to your question. (Note: A hole is just an abstraction for a missing **bound electron** not for a missing free electron. A hole is not a symmetrical counterpart of a free electron).

Comment: Great question I'm reading a book at the moment called 'Semiconductor Physics: An introduction by K.Seeger' to get a better idea about this kind of phenomena.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps it might be easier to start at the energy state.

Free electrons (those moving from one atom to another) are in the [conduction band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands) and holes (the lack of an electron in an orbit) are in the valence band (same link).

The conduction band is at a higher energy level than the valence band and that means that things move faster. More interestingly, for an electron to move from the conduction band to the valence band (and fill the hole) it must lose some energy.

From a more intuitive perspective, when a hole appears in a valence orbit, not all possible electrons will drop into it; quite a number will pass by until an electron that has (crucially) lost sufficient energy to move into a lower energy band will fill the hole.

When said electron left an orbit (creating a hole), it was because it had energy added perhaps by a collision or even just from heat (otherwise it could not take on a higher energy location in the conduction band). Only when it has used up that energy (by moving or maybe colliding with another object which can eject a photon - this means the electron has lost 1 photon worth of energy) can it lose that extra energy and drop into the valence band.

This is perhaps explained by a more detailed look at [energy levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level)

Comment: This answer makes sense, I was looking for an explanation and found this: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101101081211AAzjjDc  which basically states the same. electrons in conduction band; holes in valence band.

Comment: Thanks Bro for clearing my doubt. Now I  am thinking in right way!

Comment: Note that an electron in the conduction band *cannot* lose the "extra" energy *before* it finds a hole in the valence band to move into -- losing energy and moving to a different energy level are the same thing. So basically, in order for an electron and a hole to merge, three things must be present at the same time: the electron, the hole, and something to absorb the extra energy. In [some cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) the extra energy may be radiated away as light; in other cases, the substrate atoms absorb it as kinetic (heat) energy.

Comment: I was trying to keep the answer simple, of course. The underlying issue that an electron will find a position commensurate with its energy level is my primary point and that higher energy levels equate to higher mobility.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: An electron in the conduction band *can* lose the extra energy, if there is a vacant state below it. Of whichever nature: a conventional hole, a vacancy in the same (conduction) band, or [a doping-created bound state](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234828/extrinsic-semiconductors-why-cant-electrons-holes-in-the-band-gap-conduct).