# How to prototype with sensitive electrical components without a PCB?

Tags: rf, noise, breadboard, prototyping, protoboard

Right now I'm trying to get consistent radio operation with an NRF24L01+ and a Teensy 3.6, however in my experience working with radios they have extremely inconsistent connectivity when using breadboards, and also when using female to female dupont wires.

The only thing I've ever done in the past that works consistently is to hard solder everything to a prototyping board. However this isn't ideal as it takes a very long time and for the rocket club I'm working on the boards are too valuable to permanantly modify this way.

What is the standard way to rapidly prototype circuits which include sensitive electronics?

Comment: If you're building boards for model rockets, requiring small size and mechanical robustness, it may be time to graduate to full-fledged custom printed circuit boards. You may be surprised how fast and inexpensive they are to have fabbed now. I recommend: https://oshpark.com

Comment: Yeah this is precicely what another popular answer said here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33719/how-to-prototype. Unfortunately I'm more of a Computer Science student dabbling in EE and just don't have the time to learn PCB design. Basically I need something more beginner accessible, even if I would love to learn to make my own PCB's one day.